# Label floating beside input when resizing browser window

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create a static register form. Unfortunately the label next to the input keeps floating to the left when the browser window is maximized. I want the whole box to stay the same even when resizing. It should look like this.

[image]

I am using [Bootswatch: Yeti](https://bootswatch.com/yeti/) instead of normal bootstrap. Does anyone know a fix for this?

**MY CODE**

*HTML*

```
<form class="form-horizontal registerbox">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Register</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Firstname</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder=""></input>
      </div>
      <label for="inputSurname" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Surname</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSurname" placeholder=""></input>
      </div>
      <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="mail" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder=""></input>
      </div>
      <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder=""></input>
      </div>
      <label for="inputPasswordConf" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPasswordConf" placeholder=""></input>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center" style="width: 100%; background-color: #1fad5c; border-color: #f5f5f5;">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

*CSS*

```
.registerbox {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 19px;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7; 
}
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ob1jn05k/1/) so you can experiment with my code yourself.

Comment: You mean, on the same line?

Comment: Instead of staying on the same line it should look like the picture above shows. @romuleald

Comment: I'm not sure that the question is clear to me because it's what it do in the fiddle!

Comment: You'd need to resize the jsfiddle window to see the effect. @romuleald

Comment: I did, and it's exactlly the screen you show. Did you mean that you want the `.registerbox` to have a max-width instead a width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put label inside the div containing input field. So, instead of this:

```
<label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputName">Firstname</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <input id="inputName" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="">
</div>
```

your HTML should look something like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputName">Firstname</label>
    <input id="inputName" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="">
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ob1jn05k/5/.